# cordova.InAppBrowser does not open url with system browser

Tags: cordova-plugins

Cordova plugin InAppBrowser is opening with InAppBrowser even when I set it to `'_system'`

```js
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
  cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://google.com', '_system')
}
```

it is opening as if it were `_blank`, that is, i't not using the system browser.

#### My specs:

I'm using cordova 10

My specs

```
Cordova Packages:

    cli: 10.0.0
        common: 4.0.2
        create: 3.0.0
        lib: 10.0.0
            common: 4.0.2
            fetch: 3.0.0
            serve: 4.0.0

Project Installed Platforms:

    android: 9.0.0
    browser: null

Project Installed Plugins:

    cordova-pdf-generator: 2.1.1
    cordova-plugin-camera: 4.0.3
    cordova-plugin-compat: 1.2.0
    cordova-plugin-device: 2.0.3
    cordova-plugin-email-composer: 0.8.15
    cordova-plugin-file-transfer: 1.7.1
    cordova-plugin-file: 6.0.1
    cordova-plugin-geolocation: 2.4.3
    cordova-plugin-inappbrowser: 3.2.0
    cordova-plugin-is-debug: 1.0.0
    cordova-plugin-mobile-ocr: 3.1.1
    cordova-plugin-network-information: 2.0.2
    cordova-plugin-screen-orientation: 3.0.2
    cordova-plugin-simple-image-resizer: 0.1.1
    cordova-plugin-splashscreen: 6.0.0
    cordova-plugin-statusbar: 2.4.3
    cordova-plugin-whitelist: 1.3.4
    es6-promise-plugin: 4.2.2
    info.protonet.imageresizer: 0.1.1

Environment:

    OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (linux 5.4.0-48-generic) x64
    Node: v12.18.4
    npm: 6.14.8

android Environment:

    android:
*************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
*************************************************************************
Running /home/joao/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager list target

Available Android targets:==============] 100% Fetch remote repository...       
----------
id: 1 or "android-24"
     Name: Android API 24
     Type: Platform
     API level: 24
     Revision: 2
----------
id: 2 or "android-25"
     Name: Android API 25
     Type: Platform
     API level: 25
     Revision: 3
----------
id: 3 or "android-26"
     Name: Android API 26
     Type: Platform
     API level: 26
     Revision: 2
----------
id: 4 or "android-27"
     Name: Android API 27
     Type: Platform
     API level: 27
     Revision: 3
----------
id: 5 or "android-28"
     Name: Android API 28
     Type: Platform
     API level: 28
     Revision: 6
----------
id: 6 or "android-29"
     Name: Android API 29
     Type: Platform
     API level: 29
     Revision: 4
----------
id: 7 or "android-R"
     Name: Android API 29, R preview (Preview)
     Type: Platform
     API level: R
     Revision: 4


Project Setting Files:

    config.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.form.parking.violation" version="2.5.5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>Denúncia Estacionamento</name>
  <description>
        Envio de queixa de estacionamento ilegal a autoridade competente
    </description>
  <author email="peao.exaltado@gmail.com" href="http://passeiolivre.org">
        Caminhante
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <icon height="512" src="res/icon/universal/icon4_512x512_playstore.png" width="512"/>
  <icon density="xhdpi" height="196" src="res/icon/universal/icon4_XHDPI_196x196_320dpi.png" width="196"/>
  <icon density="xxxhdpi" height="192" src="res/icon/universal/icon4_XXXHDPI_192x192_640dpi.png" width="192"/>
  <icon density="xxhdpi" height="144" src="res/icon/universal/icon4_XXHDPI_144x144_480dpi.png" width="144"/>
  <icon density="hdpi" height="72" src="res/icon/universal/icon4_HDPI_72x72_240dpi.png" width="72"/>
  <icon density="mdpi" height="48" src="res/icon/universal/icon4_MDPI_48x48_160dpi.png" width="48"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0"/>
  <preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="10.0"/>
  <preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library,library-nosync,documents,documents-nosync,cache,bundle"/>
  <preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,assets"/>
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false"/>
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#FFFFFF"/>
  <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="blacktranslucent"/>
  <hook src="scripts/importNpmPackages.js" type="before_prepare"/>
  <hook src="scripts/copyCredentials.js" type="before_prepare"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22"/>
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="29"/>
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
    <icon height="512" src="res/icon/android/512.png" width="512"/>
    <icon density="xhdpi" height="192" src="res/icon/android/192.png" width="192"/>
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" height="192" src="res/icon/android/192.png" width="192"/>
    <icon density="xxhdpi" height="144" src="res/icon/android/144.png" width="144"/>
    <icon density="hdpi" height="72" src="res/icon/android/72.png" width="72"/>
    <icon density="mdpi" height="48" src="res/icon/android/48.png" width="48"/>
    <splash density="hdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"/>
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"/>
    <splash density="ldpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"/>
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"/>
    <splash density="mdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"/>
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"/>
    <splash density="xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png"/>
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png"/>
    <hook src="scripts/minifyFiles.js" type="after_prepare"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  </platform>
</widget>

    package.json:
--- Start of Cordova JSON Snippet ---
{
  "plugins": {
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
    "cordova-plugin-email-composer": {},
    "info.protonet.imageresizer": {},
    "cordova-plugin-simple-image-resizer": {
      "ANDROID_EXIFINTERFACES_VERSION": "27.+"
    },
    "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
    "cordova-plugin-file": {},
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
    "cordova-plugin-device": {},
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
    "cordova-plugin-mobile-ocr": {},
    "cordova-plugin-compat": {},
    "cordova-pdf-generator": {},
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
    "cordova-plugin-is-debug": {}
  },
  "platforms": [
    "browser",
    "android"
  ]
}
--- End of Cordova JSON Snippet ---
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use wkwebview

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(link, '_blank', 'usewkwebview=yes');
```